# Why aren't member functions of std:allocator static

Tags: c++, stl

[`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) is **stateless**. In other words, memory allocated by `a1.allocate()` (`a1` is one instance of `std::allocator`) can be released by `a2.deallocate()`(`a2` is another instance of `std::allocator`).

Why aren't they static member functions?

(edited on Oct 17, 2014:)

Ok, thanks to luk32. Since C++11 the custom `allocator` can have **states**, this might be the reason why `std::allocator` have those non static member functions.

Comment: I am not sure if the question is obsolete. Since c++11 custom allocators can have state. And since c++11 there actually are static versions in [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). But I dunno what was rationale previously, if there was any. So just a comment.

Comment: @luk32, implementations were always allowed to support stateful allocators even before C++11, they just weren't _required_ to support them. The static functions in `allocator_traits` all take an allocator as the first argument, and try to call the function on that first, so they're not really stateless; you still need an allocator object.

Comment: So the question is 6 yrs old and still not answered. "Custom" allocator can have states is NOT an answer to why `std::allocator` being stateless but the member function is not `static`.